# How large is "1 large beef bouillon cube" for risotto?

Tags: italian-cuisine

I am am making a bell pepper risotto. The recipe calls for 1 large beef bullion cube. I have packets that are roughly .15oz (4g) per packet. Is a normal beef bullion cube considered large? What size is the large?

Comment: Find a different recipe. Beef bouillon is one of the nastier things in a modern kitchen. I would argue that plain old water would produce better results than any broth made with beef bouillon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would check the recipe and see how much stock that requires, and then compare that to how much stock your bouillon cubes make. If it's close, you're probably fine. This assumes you make standard stock before using the cube, of course, and not concentrate. Does the recipe give any other clues?

If you can't get any joy this way, I'd suggest you just guess, erring on the side of bland, and taste as you go.

Comment: I checked. 1 packet = 1 normal cube = 1 cup of broth. Called someone who said 1 large cube = 2 cups of broth. Recipe called for using 5 cups (probably supposed to be watered down). So I went with 2 packets. Thanks.

Comment: The amount of stock required varies based on a number of factors... that's why it's added slowly. The "correct" quantity of stock is "enough to add until the risotto is cooked" :-)